# UIView's background color keeps reverting back to original color upon completion

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, uiviewanimation, uibackgroundcolor

Is there any reason why the `backgroundColor` of a `UIView` would jump back to its original color after changing it's color property in a nested `UIView.animate` method? I set it to clear during the animation then it jumps back to white upon my last second to last completion.

I have tried converting over to `animateWithKeyframes` and I still have a similar condition.

Basically I am trying to use a view as a mask and animate it across a label. I have a `darkModeBool` that indicates if the user wants a dark theme. I want the label.textColor and the view.Background color to change accordingly to my set theme protocol when it hits that animation block if that `darkModeBool` is set to true.

```
func animateGraphic() {
    firstMaskWidthConstraint.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.firstMaskView.backgroundColor = .clear
        print("1")
    }) { (_) in
        self.secondMaskHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.secondMaskView.backgroundColor = .clear
            print("2")
        }, completion: { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.8, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.view.backgroundColor = SproutTheme.current.backgroundColor.cgColor
                self.sproutLabel.textColor = SproutTheme.current.textColor

            }, completion: { (_) in
                RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1.8))
                self.popToNavigationStack()
            })
        })
    }
}
```

When the view is supposed to change it's `backgroundColor` in the second to last completion, the `firstMaskView` and `secondMaskView` go back to white covering the text. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to set backgroundColor to view itself not to layer...

Comment: @user3344236 thanks for that I forgot that I hadn't changed that back. I was seeing if by accessing the layer if t would have any affect. I changed it back to self.view.backgroundColor and it's still the same. The problem is with firstMaskView and the secondMaskView.

Comment: Figured out it was the text property of the underlying label that did not like UIView.animate. Used UIView.transition and it worked. Also came with a nice set of options :). Thanks !